# How can I give string to translate?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-intl

I am using  key - value translation-`S.of(context).translation_key`- but I need something like `"Translation string".translate()` or `translate("Translation string")`

How can I do this ?

I am using localizely plugin.
Flutter version is lastest.

Attention: I am not asking for `translate("key")` I am asking `translate("Translate String")`
I want to give a value and get current translation value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to do it the other way:

```
String _localeCode = 'en';
```

Your method:

```
String translate(String key) {
  if (_localeCode == 'en') {
    if (key == 'key1') return 'English translation for key1';
    else if (key == 'key2') return 'English translation for key2';
  } else if (_localeCode == 'es') {
    if (key == 'key1') return 'Spanish translation for key1';
    else if (key == 'key2') return 'Spanish translation for key2';
  }
}
```

And you'd use it:

```
void main() {
  var translatedString = translate('key1');
}
```

For simplicity I hardcoded the things, but a better solution is to load the keys through a json file, [here's a better approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57307168/6618622)

Comment: My company bought the plugin for 1 year. At the moment, I can't go thro json file but I got idea from this. I will something

Comment: Plus you didn't understand the question. I already have KEY - VALUE translation system. 
I want to give a Value and get current translation Value
For Example: 
`En => App Title` | `Another Lang => Title App`
I will give **App Title** and get **Title App**.